# 'blocked by CORS policy' on client-side only

Tags: reactjs, cors, next.js

I have a problem on my next.js app.
I try to make a get request from the client side on this endpoint:
`https://fr.pornhub.com/webmasters/search`

when the request is made on back side all work but when she is send from client i get cors error

The problem is if I try to make it like that

```js
return
 fetch('http://www.pornhub.com/webmasters/search?page=2', {
    headers: {
      // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  })
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
```

I get this error:

> 'Access to fetch at `'http://www.pornhub.com/webmasters/search?page=2'`
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'

And if I uncomment Access-Control-Allow-Origin this I get this one:

> 'Access to fetch at `'http://www.pornhub.com/webmasters/search?page=2'`
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
>   Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.'

If I understand goodly I can't use options on this endpoint but I cannot add Access-Control-Allow-Origin without option preflight?

So how resolve that?

Comment: You might need to proxy that request through the backend. Not sure about how next.js works, but it would be through node.

Comment: Assuming that the site you are querying will allow the request to begin with, and doesn't require authentication or an API key of some kind.  Also, I applaud you for leaving the original URL!

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header that has to be added by the **server** on the **response**.  It is not up to the client to tell the server that it should have access, in relation to CORS.  If any client could just add a header to get around CORS, it wouldn't be much of a security mechanism.

Comment: but why the request work on backend side ?

Comment: CORS only applies to requests made from the client from one domain to another, where the request has an Origin or Referrer header.  Requests made from a server to another server, are not ajax, and do not fall under the same restrictions.  Same way that if the client were to take a url and put it straight into their browser address bar, or to call the url from a REST client, the CORS restrictions would not apply, as both of those methods of requesting a resource from a user do not add the Origin or Referrer header to them, signifying that they originated from another domain.

Comment: ok thanks Taplar, so there is no way to request this endpoint from front-end whitout edit it ?